# Regex to split the words before and after space and line break

Tags: regex

I'm trying to split FIRST name, MIDDLE name (optional) and LAST name that are written over one or two lines like that:

- FIRST MIDDLE
  LAST
- FIRST
  LAST
- FIRST LAST

I managed to end up with the following regex for the MIDDLE and the LAST name. It matches all text before the line break:

```
(?i)\w{1,}(?=\r)
```

and for the last name, the following regex would match all text after a line break:

```
(?i)(?<=\n)\w{1,}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work in these cases:

1. It doesn't work at all when the name is written over one line only like in the 3rd scenario;
2. When there is a middle name and it's over 2 lines like in the 1st scenario, it only gets the LAST and MIDDLE.

Comment: Is this in a specific programming language? Maybe a regex isn't the solution, so if you include more information, we'll be able to provide clearer directions.

Comment: You obviously have delimiters around that string, using them in your regex will help so much. you should tell us the context

Comment: I'm using these regex within a data capture software called PSI-Capture. I use them as a mask when capturing a zone OCR. I tried to work it out using C# scripting as the software allows that; but since my scripting skills are very limited I couldn't work it out so I'm back to regex masking.